Send a fixed value that is not a text box
I have a code that sends the value only if it is in a text box. The name value is required to be sent

<?php
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $fi = file("data.txt");
    $t0 = trim($_POST['t0']);
    $t1 = trim($_POST['t1']);
    $file_data = "$t0||$t1\r\n";
    $file_data .= file_get_contents('data.txt');
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $file_data );
}
}
?>


Plain text is not sent from a HTML form. If you require the name to be sent when the form is submitted, you can put it into a hidden field in the form as well.
